# Is it possible to restrict certain commands from being run in a directory?

Tags: shell, command-line, git

I have two directories: `src` and `projects`. I would like to prevent myself from running `git ...` unless I am specifically inside `src` or `projects`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is difficult to prevent the binary from being run but for the typical situations an easy protection method exists:

1. You define a shell function that overwrites the name. This will obviously not work in another (also another user's) shell.
2. You take the binary out of the $PATH and replace it by a wrapper script. This is safer but will obviously cause problems with software updates (the script gets overwritten).

The shell function could look like this:

```
git () {
  local cwd="$(pwd -P)"
  if ! [ "/path/to/src" = "$cwd" -o "/path/to/projects" = "$cwd" ]; then
    echo "The current working directory is: '${cwd}'"
    echo "git must not be run from here; from src and projects only."
    echo "Aborting."
  else
    command git "$@"
  fi
}
```

Comment: This is an acceptable solution for me - I'm going to wait a bit and see if any other options pop up. If not, I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

An unusual one: if using `zsh`, you could use region highlighting to flag in bold red the `git` word if used while `$PWD` is not where you want. Like:

```
self-insert() {
  zle .$WIDGET
  if [[ $BUFFER = git(| *) && $PWD != */src && $PWD != */projects ]]; then
    region_highlight=("0 3 fg=red,bold,standout")
  else
    region_highlight=()
  fi
}
zle -N self-insert
```

That way, it doesn't get in your way, but let you know of a potential problem.

To flag `git` anywhere on the line:

```
self-insert() {
  zle .$WIDGET
  if [[ $BUFFER =~ '\<git\>' && $PWD != */src && $PWD != */projects ]]; then
    region_highlight=("$((MBEGIN-1)) $MEND fg=red,bold,standout")
  else
    region_highlight=()
  fi
}
zle -N self-insert
```

Example:

[image: example]