# How to restrict rm -rf / in CentOS machine?

Tags: linux, centos

I would like to know how we can restrict `rm -rf /`on CentOS machines?

Comment: By default it shouldn't do any harm on recent versions as long as you don't use `--no-preserve-root`.

Comment: If you're in doubt, set up a VM and have some fun with `rm` just to get a feeling about what works and what doesn't.

Comment: [See this similar question][1] about another command.


  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77696/is-it-possible-to-restrict-certain-commands-from-being-run-in-a-directory/77700#77700

Comment: Create `/usr/local/bin/rm` which plays *Jingle Bells* instead of removing files.

Comment: "Restrict" how?

Comment: Not running as root should prevent most of the harm that `rm -rf /` would otherwise do.

Answer (score 2):

Check out **Safe-rm**, it's basically a wrapper around `rm` that skips by default important directories (`/`, `/bin`, etc):

```
$ rm -rf /usr
Skipping /usr
```

Comment: The danger to such an approach (regardless of the exact tool; even `alias rm='rm -i` comes with such a caveat) is that you run the risk of getting used to having such protections in place, and then don't realize until it's too late when you're working on a system that *doesn't* have them. Instead, consider the fact that with great power comes great responsibility. Being logged in as root should not be taken lightly, and even as an ordinary user, `rm -rf ~` can do quite a bit of damage if you don't have current backups. Moral of the story: **have backups!**

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to restrict directories is to use sudo. If you add an user to the sudoers file and they go `rm -rf --no-preserve-root /` then there isn't much you can do, but normal users (not in the sudoers file) won't be allowed to do that at all.